# Why doesn't "sort file1 > file1" work?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, redirect, pipe

When I am trying to sort a file and save the sorted output in itself, like this

```
sort file1 > file1;
```

the contents of the file1 is getting erased altogether, whereas when i am trying to do the same with 'tee' command like this

```
sort file1 | tee file1;
```

it works fine *[ed: "works fine" only for small files with lucky timing, will cause lost data on large ones or with unhelpful process scheduling]*, i.e it is overwriting the sorted output of file1 in itself and also showing it on standard output.

Can someone explain why the first case is not working?

Comment: Dup of [SORT empties my file?](http://superuser.com/q/142504/7542)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work because '>' redirection implies truncation, and to avoid keeping the whole output of `sort` in the memory before re-directing to the file, bash truncates and redirects output before running `sort`. Thus, contents of the `file1` file will be truncated before `sort` will have a chance to read it.

Comment: It's not 'to avoid keeping the whole output of sort in the memory before re-directing to the file', and it isn't peculiar to 'bash'. The defined precedence of `>` means that it is evaluated before executing the program, simple as that, in all shells.

Answer (score 20):

As other people explained, the problem is that the I/O redirection is done before the `sort` command is executed, so the file is truncated before `sort` gets a chance to read it.  If you think for a bit, the reason why is obvious - the shell handles the I/O redirection, and must do that before running the command.

The `sort` command has 'always' (since at least Version 7 UNIX) supported a `-o` option to make it safe to output to one of the input files:

```
sort -o file1 file1 file2 file3
```

The trick with `tee` depends on timing and luck (and probably a small data file).  If you had a megabyte or larger file, I expect it would be clobbered, at least in part, by the `tee` command.  That is, if the file is large enough, the `tee` command would open the file for output and truncate it before `sort` finished reading it.

Answer (score 6):

It's unwise to depend on either of these command to work the way you expect.

The way to modify a file in place is to write the modified version to a new file, then rename the new file to the original name:

```
sort file1 > file1.tmp && mv file1.tmp file1
```

This avoids the problem of reading the file after it's been partially modified, which is likely to mess up the results.  It also makes it possible to deal gracefully with errors; if the file is N bytes long, and you only have N/2 bytes of space available on the file system, you can detect the failure creating the temporary file and not do the rename.

Or you can rename the original file, then read it and write to a new file with the same name:

```
mv file1 file1.bak && sort file1.bak > file1
```

Some commands have options to modify files in place (for example, `perl` and `sed` both have `-i` options (note that the syntax of sed's `-i` option can vary).  But these options work by creating temporary files; it's just done internally.

Comment: Nice - but `sort -o file1 file1` is much simpler and safer.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection has higher precedence. So in the first case, > file1 executes first and empties the file.

Answer (score 1):

The first command doesn't work (`sort file1 > file1`), because when using the redirection operator (`>` or `>>`) shell creates/truncates file before the `sort` command is even invoked, since it has higher precedence.

The second command works (`sort file1 | tee file1`), because `sort` reads lines from the file first, then writes sorted data to standard output.

So when using any other similar command, you should avoid using redirection operator when reading and writing into the same file, but you should use relevant in-place editors for that (e.g. `ex`, `ed`, `sed`), for example:

```
ex '+%!sort' -cwq file1
```

or use other utils such as `sponge`.

Luckily for `sort` there is the `-o` parameter which write results to the file (as suggested by [@Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935970/55075)), so the solution is straight forward: `sort -o file1 file1`.

Answer (score 0):

Bash open a new empty file when reads the pipe, and then calls to sort.

In the second case, tee opens the file after sort has already read the contents.

Comment: 'tee' opens its file at some indeterminate time relative to when 'sort' opens its file. Sometimes you get lucky, sometimes you don't. It isn't necessary that 'sort' has read all the contents, only that it has opened the file first.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this method

```
sort file1 -o file1
```

This will sort and store back to the original file.  Also, you can use this command to remove duplicated line:

```
sort -u file1 -o file1
```

Comment: And doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: If you decide to answer an older question that has well established and
correct answers, adding a new answer late in the day may not get you any
credit.
If you have some distinctive new information, or you're convinced the
other answers are all wrong, by all means add a new answer, but 'yet
another answer' giving the same basic information a long time after the
question was asked usually won't earn you much credit.  This answer explains how to avoid the problem, but the question was "why is there a problem".