# Redirection Doesn't Work

Tags: shell, ubuntu, io-redirection

I want to put my program's output into a file. I keyed in the following :

```
./prog > log 2>&1
```

But there is nothing in the file **"log"**. I am using the Ubuntu 11.10 and the default shell is bash.

Anybody know the cause of this AND how I can debug this?

Comment: If you just run ./prog, does it produce any output?

Comment: @Moishe: Yes. There are a bunch of printf statements in my program.

Comment: @Moishe: does calling a library, which does print out as well, have potential problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible causes:

- The program reads the input from `log` file while you try to redirect into it with truncation (see [Why doesn't "sort file1 > file1" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935512/why-doesnt-sort-file1-file1-work/7935539#7935539))
- The output is buffered so that you don't see data in the file until the output buffer is flushed. You can manually call `fflush` or output `std::flush` if using C++ I/O stream etc.
- The program is smart enough and disables output if the output stream is not a terminal.
- You look at the wrong file (i.e. in another directory).
- You try to dump file's contents incorrectly.
- Your program outputs '\0' as the first character so the output appears to be empty, even though there is some data.
- Name your own.

Your best bet is to run this application under a debugger (like `gdb`) or use `strace` or `ptrace` (or both) and see what the program is doing. I mean, really, output redirection works for the last like 40 years, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: My program doesn't take input. And there were just a bunch of printf statements. Well, I did use the gnu scientific library and some of its routines have printf statements too. I guess I will try flushing the stdout buffer. Any quick way to do it in C?

Comment: @Rich: In C, `fflush (stdout);` does the job fairly well.

Comment: When I don't use the library (gsl btw) the redirection works find. whenever I call the function (simulated annealing if it matters), redirection doesn't work anymore. Does the library mess up anything? in the manual for gsl_simulated_annealing, it says "it will print to stdout". Would there be contention for the output stream? I have no idea as to how to use gdb to trace redirection though.