# Redirection to file produces no output

Tags: command-line-arguments, io-redirection

I have a program which uses the OpenCL libraries and produces some output on to stdout. The program accepts some command line arguments depending on which the kernel is run on a CPU or a GPU.

When I run the program on GPU,

```
$./run 1
$./run 1 > outFile
```

(a) Without any redirection, the output is seen on the stdout.

(b) With redirection to a file, the output is redirected to a the file specified.

When I run the program on a CPU,

```
$./run 0
$./run 0 > outFile
```

(a) Without any redirection, the output is seen on the stdout.

(b) With redirection to a file, no output is seen in the file.

Its a arch linux machine, with bash. If any other information is required, please let me know.

Comment: I happened to find the answer at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004319/redirection-doesnt-work). An `fflush(stdout)` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
$./run 0 >& outFile
```

Comment: Still the same. No output upon redirection.

Comment: What about $./run 0 >| outFile?

Comment: Still no output on redirection.