# input file is output file error

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error, cat

I'm trying to run the command

```
find . -name "*.csv" | xargs -I{} cat '{}' > Everything2.csv
```

and I get back:

> cat: ./Everything2.csv: input file is output file

What does this mean?

Comment: It means the input file is the output file.  `find` is finding `Everything2.csv` and xargs is invoking `cat` with `Everything2.csv` as the input file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "sort file1 > file1" work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935512/why-doesnt-sort-file1-file1-work)

Comment: `find . -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 cat` is generally the safer practice, if you want to use `xargs`. Look at what your existing code does if some of your CSV files have spaces or quotes in their names; it's not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in that [answer](https://superuser.com/a/703964/87805), you should run:

```
$ find . -name '*.csv' -exec cat {} + | tee Everything2.csv
```

since redirection operator  (`>` or `>>`) has a higher precedence, therefore it creating/truncating the file, before the `find` command is invoked. So to avoid that you need to generate the list first, then pipe it into the file, but without using redirection operator, so `tee` in this cause works fine.

Alternatively use `sponge` instead of `cat` which soaks up standard input and write to a file:

```
find . -name "*.csv" | xargs -I{} sponge '{}' > Everything2.csv
```

Comment: The suggested code works only if the output file doesn't already exist. If there's a file present whose contents we're trying to replace, the same issue can occur.

Answer (score 2):

Tell `find` to exclude the output file from its results to prevent this loop:

```
find . -name Everything2.csv -prune -o \
       -name '*.csv' -exec cat {} + \
  >Everything2.csv
```